# How to split into train/test keeping a single row in the training set? Stratified function R equivalent in Python

Tags: python, r, sample, train-test-split

My dataset has categorical variables with only one observation in a class, in R this observation belongs to the training set, but in python return error. How to allocate this row in train automatically?

R script

```
> dataset = data.frame(target = c(100,200,300), Var1 = c("a","b","b"))
> split <- stratified(dataset,c("Var1"), 0.70, keep.rownames=TRUE, bothSets=TRUE)
> train <- split$SAMP1
> train
   rn target Var1
1:  1    100    a
2:  3    300    b
> test <- split$SAMP2
> test
   rn target Var1
1:  2    200    b
```

Python

```
data = [[100, 'a'], [200, 'b'], [300, 'b']]
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Target', 'Var1'])
train, test = train_test_split(dataset, stratify = dataset[['Var1']], train_size = 0.7)
ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please edit your question into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier for others to help?

Comment: Of course! Simple example to help